# unable to move the cursor inside the edit field in the row in ng grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ng-grid

I am using nggrid 2.x version ,I want to move the cursor inside the text field in the rows but the arrow keys has no effect on the edit field.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding fllowing grid options
tabIndex: 0,
noTabInterference: true

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

```
 onKeyDown = (event): void => {
    const { keyCode, target, shiftKey } = event;
    if (shiftKey) {
      if (keyCode === 37) {
        const { selectionStart } = target;
        if (selectionStart !== null && selectionStart) {
          target.selectionStart = selectionStart - 1;
        }
      } else if (keyCode === 39) {
        const { selectionEnd } = target;
        if (selectionEnd !== null) {
          target.selectionEnd = selectionEnd + 1;
        }
      }
    } else if (keyCode === 37) {
      const selection = target.selectionStart;
      if (selection !== null && selection) {
        target.selectionStart = selection - 1;
        target.selectionEnd = selection - 1;
      }
    } else if (keyCode === 39) {
      const selection = target.selectionStart;
      if (selection !== null) {
        target.selectionStart = selection + 1;
        target.selectionEnd = selection + 1;
      }
    } else if (keyCode === 35) {
      target.selectionStart = get(target, 'value.length', 0);
      target.selectionEnd = get(target, 'value.length', 0);
    } else if (keyCode === 36) {
      target.selectionStart = 0;
      target.selectionEnd = 0;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. Please consider adding a brief explanation how your code solves the issue.